# How to change white background to transparent in golang?

Tags: image, go, transparent

How to change a Golang `image.Image`'s white background to transparent?

I want to put the white background into a translucent color, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] showing what you've tried?

Comment: What is the context here? Are you making a webpage? A desktop application?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in general but there are heuristic approaches to attempt this.

Why is it not possible?

If the original image had some transparent pixels and was rendered on a plain white background (or any known background) then in the resulting image there is lost information.  For example, is a pink pixel created from a red pixel with some transparency or a truly pink pixel without transparency?

Even a pure white pixel may have been fully white originally, or fully transparent, or somewhere in between.

Heuristic approaches

If you know something about the original image or can infer something by looking at it you may be able to deduce what colour and transparency of the original pixels was.  A simple first step is that if the outside pixels are white then you might want to flood fill this area with fully transparent pixels. Also white areas inside coloured areas *may* be holes that can also be transparent.

Next you can infer the colours of border pixels around objects of a single colour (assuming transparency was used for anti-aliasing).  For example for a red circle with pink pixels on the circumference it's likely they were originally red with some transparency leading them to be rendered in different shades of pink. For more complex, multi-coloured shapes you can get a reasonable result by manually editing the image using judgement, knowledge/guesswork of the original image and knowledge of how anti-aliasing was performed.

I wrote a Paint.Net plugin (C#) to automate this sort of thing many years ago and sometimes it gave reasonable results, but often you need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

package "image" has Decode function

```
func Decode(r io.Reader) (Image, string, error)
```

image.Image is interface

```
type Image interface {
        // ColorModel returns the Image's color model.
        ColorModel() color.Model
        // Bounds returns the domain for which At can return non-zero color.
        // The bounds do not necessarily contain the point (0, 0).
        Bounds() Rectangle
        // At returns the color of the pixel at (x, y).
        // At(Bounds().Min.X, Bounds().Min.Y) returns the upper-left pixel of the grid.
        // At(Bounds().Max.X-1, Bounds().Max.Y-1) returns the lower-right one.
        At(x, y int) color.Color
}
```

after you decode you file into image.Image, you can get Height and Width from Bounds(),and color from At(x,y).

So, here is what to do next:

- make another image with alpha channel,
- Iterate throw whole image one pix by another,
- check color, copy color to new image after you do whatever you want.